# equisatisfiable symbol in logic

Tags: logic

I'm learning about the Skolem algorithm, equisatisfiability in First Order Logic and see that the book Mathematical Logic for Computer Science uses the symbol  $ \approx $  to indicate equisatisfiability.

Is there any standard symbol for equisatisfiability? I think that the use of $ \approx $ is not really good because people may misinterpret it as *approximation*

Comment: Misinterpreted by who? If the things either side of the $\approx$ symbol are first order formulae then it's unlikely a logician reading it will think it means approximation.

Comment: Equiprovability (which coincides with equisatisfiability in first order logic) is often written using back-to-back turnstiles: $\phi \mathrel{\dashv\vdash} \psi$. (But I agree with Clive Newstead that little confusion is likely to arise from using $\approx$.)

Comment: CliveNewstead and Rob Arthan: Thank you for commenting. I'm newbie to this field and your comments made me clearer :-)